# Angular passing variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, http, couchdb

I am trying to pass variables between to different functions in a controller. Here is the code that I am using to do this:

HTML:

```
<table class="flat-table">
            <tr>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Controls</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="doc in guest.docs">
                <td>{{doc.value.user}}</td>
                <td>{{doc.value.comment}}</td>
                <td>{{doc.value.date}}</td>
                <td>
                    <img class="controls" src="styles/delete.png" ng-click="guest.delete(doc.id)" title="Delete">
                    <img class="controls" src="styles/edit.png" ng-click="guest.visible = true; guest.editBox(doc.id)" title="Edit">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="signCon">
            <form name="addForm" ng-submit="guest.add()">
                <textarea type="text" ng-model="guest.signature.comment" id="comment" placeholder="Enter a comment?!" required></textarea>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign!">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="editCon" ng-show="guest.visible === true">
        <h1>Edit</h1>
        <p>Here you can alter your comment.</p>
        <form name="editForm" ng-submit="guest.submitEdit(guest.editBox.signature)">
            <textarea type="text" ng-model="guest.submitEdit.comment" required></textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit!">
        </form>
    </div>
```

ANGULAR:

```
this.editBox = function(id) {
            var that = this;
            this.id = id;
            this.signature = {};
            if(self.visible) {
                $http({
                    url: 'http://ip:5984/guestbook/' + this.id,
                    method: 'GET',
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': auth_hash(UserService.get().username, UserService.get().password)
                    }
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    that.signature = data;
                    console.log(that.signature);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("error!")
                });
            };
        };
        this.submitEdit = function(signature){
            var self = this;
            this.comment = '';
            this.signature = signature;
            console.log(this.signature);
        };
```

The idea is that when the user clicks on the edit image a new window appears and they are able to enter a new comment and re submit it. the window displays correctly and I am able to pull the object correctly. It's when trying to call the submitEdit function It does not seem to pass through the signature variable. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Can you please post the full controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you are not creating a new instance of editBox that persistently stores properties, so guest.editBox.signature only exists while the editBox function is running, it does not persist.

What you can do is create a new variable in the scope outside of editBox, something like

```
this.signature = {};
```

Then within editBox you can assign the signature object to the newly created this.signature.

In your editForm you can call ng-submit with

```
ng-submit="guest.submitEdit(guest.signature)"
```

If necessary, at the end of submitEdit, you can reset this.signature back to an empty object.

p.s is there a reason you don't use $scope?